# recaptcha v3 not running second time - Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, captcha

I have a functionality in Angular that resends an activation code from a user account and I am using google recaptcha v3 to obtain the captcha token and validate it on the server.

The first time I execute the call to the captcha service, it works without problems, but when the user wants to "resend the generated code", the captcha service is executed again but it does not enter the "execute()" method but no more well, it skips it and does nothing.... Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

```
export class RecaptchaComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  public readonly executionLog: Array<OnExecuteData | OnExecuteErrorData> = [];

  private singleExecutionSubscription: Subscription;
  private allExecutionsSubscription: Subscription;
  private allExecutionErrorsSubscription: Subscription;



  constructor(private recaptchaV3Service: ReCaptchaV3Service) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.allExecutionsSubscription = this.recaptchaV3Service.onExecute.subscribe(
      (data) => this.executionLog.push(data)
    );
    this.allExecutionErrorsSubscription = this.recaptchaV3Service.onExecuteError.subscribe(
      (data) => this.executionLog.push(data)
    );
  }

  public validateBot(): Observable<any> {
    if (this.singleExecutionSubscription) {
      this.singleExecutionSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }

    return new Observable(subscriber => {

    this.singleExecutionSubscription = this.recaptchaV3Service
      .execute("validate")      
      .subscribe(
        (token) => {
          //Here it arrives in the first call, but in the second it never goes through this block or the error block
          subscriber.next(token);          
          subscriber.complete()
        },
        (error) => {
          console.error(error);          
          subscriber.error(error);
        }
      );
    })
  }

  public ngOnDestroy(): void {
    if (this.allExecutionsSubscription) {
      this.allExecutionsSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }
    if (this.allExecutionErrorsSubscription) {
      this.allExecutionErrorsSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }
    if (this.singleExecutionSubscription) {
      this.singleExecutionSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }
  }

}
```

PS: On the second try, it doesn't throw any error, it just bypasses the token block and followed by that, it strangely redirects me to my home page

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?  What do the network tools in your browser say is happening?

Comment: absolutely nothing, I don't get any errors and in the network tab no request is registered